# Carousel Controller : 'positions.isNotEmpty': PageController.page cannot be accessed before a PageView is built with it

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

In my **ScreenA** I have a  [**CarouselSlider package**](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) which I instance its controller in this way and I use it in that same screen.

```dart
  final CarouselController _carouselController = CarouselController();
```

However from **ScreenB** using **Bloc**, I make an event that calls a state that is in **ScreenA** in the following way:

**SCREEN A :**

```dart
      BlocListener<ABloc, AState>(
          bloc: context.read<ABloc>(),
          listener: (context, state) {
            switch (state.status) {
              case AStatus.saving:
                /// Exist ScreenB
                Navigator.of(context).pop();

                _carouselController.jumpToPage(0); // ERROR HERE

                break;
            [...]
```

[image: ScreenA State Bloc]

I don't understand why I get this error if I have already exited **ScreenB** and the carousel controller is right there.

*Curious fact : I get the error in my emulator but even though I have already gone through pop(), it is still in ScreenB.*

//// ALTERNATE

[image]

The variable `isImagePage` is **false** so it gets the correct controller

[image]

/////// ======= CODE ======= /////////

```dart
class _ScreenAState extends State<ScreenA> {
  final CarouselController _carouselController = CarouselController();
  final CarouselController _carouselModalController = CarouselController();


  @override
  void initState() {
    context.read<TestABloc>().add(InitStatusATest());

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocListener(
      listeners: [
        BlocListener<TestABloc, TestAState>(
          bloc: context.read<TestABloc>(),
          listener: (context, state){
            switch (state.status) {
              case TestAStatus.saving:
                /// Exits ScreenB
                Navigator.of(context).pop();

                /// Functions that calls the state to change the carousel
                context.read<PictureCarouselBloc>().add(
                  ChangeCarousel(
                     pictureList: [],
                     isImagePage: false,
                  ),
                );


                break;
              default:
            }
          },
        ),
        // * PICTURE CAROUSEL BLOC - LISTENER
        BlocListener<PictureCarouselBloc, PictureCarouselState>(
          bloc: context.read<PictureCarouselBloc>(),
          listener: (context, state) {
            switch (state.status) {
              case PictureCarouselStatus.change:
                if (mounted) {
                  if (_carouselController.ready) {
                    if (state.isAnimated) {
                      _carouselController.animateToPage(
                        state.index,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                      );
                    } else {
                      _carouselController.jumpToPage(state.index); /// ERROR HERE
                    }
                  }
                }
                break;
             
              default:
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
      child: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: null,
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          appBar: [...],
          // * TEST A BLOC - BUILDER
          body: BlocBuilder<TestABloc, TestAState>(
            bloc: context.read<TestABloc>(),
            builder: (context, state) {
              switch (state.status) {
                case TestAStatus.success:
                  return PictureCarousel(
                    carouselController: _carouselController,
                    carouselModalController: _carouselModalController,
                  );
                case TestAStatus.failure:
                  return ErrorMessage(
                    state.failureMessage,
                    isFailure: true,
                    isIcon: true,
                  );
                default:
                  return const Container();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


class PictureCarousel extends StatelessWidget {
  const PictureCarousel({
    Key? key,
    required this.carouselController,
    required this.carouselImagePageController,
  }) : super(key: key);


  final CarouselController carouselController;
  final CarouselController carouselImagePageController;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: Device.w(33),
      child: BlocBuilder<PictureCarouselBloc, PictureCarouselState>(
        bloc: context.read<PictureCarouselBloc>(),
        builder: (context, state) {
          switch (state.status) {
            case PictureCarouselStatus.change:
            case PictureCarouselStatus.success:
              return _PictureCarouselBody(
                pictureList: [],
                isImagePage: state.isImagePage,
                carouselController: carouselController,
                carouselImagePageController: carouselImagePageController,
              );
            case PictureCarouselStatus.loading:
              return const LoadingWidget();
            case PictureCarouselStatus.failure:
              return ErrorMessage(
                state.failureMessage,
                isFailure: true,
                isIcon: true,
              );
            default:
              return Container();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


// * PICTURE CAROUSEL BODY
class _PictureCarouselBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const _PictureCarouselBody({
    Key? key,
    required this.pictureList,
    required this.isImagePage,
    required this.carouselController,
    required this.carouselImagePageController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<dynamic> pictureList;
  final CarouselController carouselController;
  final CarouselController carouselImagePageController;
  final bool isImagePage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: null,

          child: SizedBox(
            width: Device.screenWidth,
            height: Device.screenHeight,
            child: CarouselSlider(
                      carouselController: isImagePage
                          ? carouselImagePageController
                          : carouselController,
                      options: CarouselOptions(
                        viewportFraction: 1.0,
                        height: _carouselHeight,
                        initialPage: state.index,
                        enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                      ),
                      items: []
                    ),
      
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }


}
```

Comment: try to alternate sequence of `controller` and `pop`.

Comment: Same error there :/ I edit the answer with the photo

Comment: How does your carousel widget look like? I think you haven't added

Comment: I edit the answer with the carousel, but for example if I do an await Future.delayed after the pop with 500 miliseconds and it works ! but i don't want to use that, it's not necessary

Comment: my suggestion is create a function which has _carouselController.jumpToPage(0); in ScreeA & pass the function to ScreenB then call this function inside ur BlocListener

Comment: Could you attach a little bit more of the code, so that we see where is `_carouselController` declared and where do you have the `BlocListener` and `CarouselSlider`?

Comment: But the BlocListener is in ScreenA because the controller is over there, why it has to be in ScreenB ?

Comment: Done, I added all the main code that i used with the Blocs and Carousel

Comment: I have the error, but when i remove the error, the emulator does the pop and the jumpToPage, idk why i have the error but it does the logic

Comment: I found the solution, the TestAStatus.saving wasn't in the Builder, so never found the PictureCarousel. Thx everybody